# Realizar un bucle condicional sobre columnas en RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy realizando unos análisis acerca del dataset de "The Ultimate Halloween Candy Power Ranking" de Kaggle.

Este dataset tiene 85 observaciones de 13 variables. Las variables interesantes son las categóricas que nos indican la presencia o no de un componente en el caramelo de estudio (por ejemplo, chocolate y fruta) y la variable continua de popularidad expresada en porcentaje.

Me interesaría obtener la media de la popularidad entre la gente cuando aparece cada uno de los componentes, es decir, me interesaría obtener esta media de popularidad por columnas. Intenté con un bucle "for" y un "if" en el interior pero no consigo dar con la tecla. Estoy intentando crear una función pero tampoco me funciona.

Esta función sería la siguiente:

```
mean <- function(x,y){
if (x == 1){
    print(mean(y))}
  }
```

*x* sería la variable chocolate (por ejemplo, que toma un valor de 1 cuando un caramelo tiene chocolate) e *y* sería la variable de popularidad. Por lo tanto, la finalidad del bucle for sería obtener una media de la popularidad por componente en una tabla.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! por favor, usa las etiquetas que ayuden a entender realmente sobre que es tu pregunta. bucle-for no es una etiqueta que por si sola, sirva para algo... tal vez decir que lenguaje es sea mucho mejor...

Comment: Estas encarando mal el problema, no necesitas un ciclo, R es un lenguaje que nativamente entiende datos vectoriales,  lo que buscas lo puedes resolver más o menos así `mean(ifelse(x == 1, y, NA), na.rm = TRUE)`. De todas formas si muestras un ejemplo de los datos, al estilo de un [mcve] tal vez podamos darte una respuesta aún mejor.